# Accessing a JSON property (String) using a variable

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to access a JSON using a variable I'm passing through a function:

```
function highlightCategory (category) {
   for (var i in data) {
      console.log(data[i].category)
   }
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, because 'category' is what I'm passing with the function and not the real name of the property, but I've been trying different possibilities unsuccessfully.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If category is a string containing the key of the JSON property, it'd be as easy as `console.log(data[category])`

Comment: It'd help if you showed your JSON ... is "category" a direct property of data or is it a sub-property of one of the direct properties?

Comment: Note: That's not JSON, that is a Javascript object. JSON is a text format to represent objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
data[i][category]
```

in JS, `obj.prop` is synonymous with `obj['prop']`.

```
var foo = {
  bar: 'baz'
};
// foo.bar == foo['bar'] == 'baz'
```

Also, you're dealing with a javascript object, not JSON (though it may have *originated* there)

**Update** for those coming across this and using ES6, you can now use variables during assignment:

```
const propName = 'bar';
const foo = {
  [propName]: 'baz',
}
// foo.bar == foo[propName] == 'baz'
```

For reference, this is considered a `ComputedPropertyName` under Object Initializer section of ES6 spec.

Comment: Brad's answer works! Thanks. I just forgot to get rid of the dot  (data[i].[category]).

Comment: @ChiquiEsteban, if it works you should accept the answer by clicking the checkbox to the left

Comment: @Austin: Probably still too soon to accept. ;-) But thanks for the enthusiasm.