# JavaScript: Dynamically call a function inside an object

Tags: javascript, function, object, oop

I have an object that contains many functions

```
var obj = {
    'Func1': function() {},
    'Func2': function() {},
    'Func3': function() {},
    'Func4': function() {}
...
}
var functionToCall = 'Func2';
```

I want to dynamically call a function inside the object using a string value. Any idea how to achieve this in JavaScript?

Comment: See [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing a JSON property (String) using a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300236/accessing-a-json-property-string-using-a-variable)

Comment: @elclanrs: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look up the object's property using `[]`, then use `()` to call the function

```
obj[functionToCall]();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access properties of object by `[]`:

```
obj['Func2']();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all there's to it :

```js
var obj = {
    'Func1': function() { alert('Func1') },
    'Func2': function() { alert('Func2') },
    'Func3': function() { alert('Func3') },
    'Func4': function() { alert('Func4') }
}

var functionToCall = 'Func2';
obj[functionToCall]();
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ueor75gx/))